# Displaying motherboard, memory, and CPU information

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a decent utility to display motherboard, memory, and CPU information in Windows?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/15216/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-a-detailed-list-of-the-hardware-in-my-windows-box

Answer (score 10):

Try [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php). It has worked great for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

One simple tool is called [System Information for Windows](http://www.gtopala.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[Belarc](http://www.belarc.com/products.html) is a popular tool also used by enterprises for auditing PCs.
A personal freeware edition called [`Belarc Advisor`](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) is also available.

Answer (score 1):

[SiSoftware Sandra Lite](http://www.sisoftware.net/index.html?dir=&location=pinformation&langx=en&a=) (the System ANalyser, Diagnostic and Reporting Assistant) is a non-commercial freeware.

> SiSoftware Sandra is an information & diagnostic
>   utility. It should provide most of the
>   information (including undocumented)
>   you need to know about your hardware,
>   software and other devices whether
>   hardware or software.
>
> It works along the lines of other
>   Windows utilities, however it tries to
>   go beyond them and show you more of
>   what's really going on. Giving the
>   user the ability to draw comparisons
>   at both a high and low-level. You can
>   get information about the CPU,
>   chipset, video adapter, ports,
>   printers, sound card, memory, network,
>   Windows internals, AGP, PCI, PCI-X,
>   PCIe (PCI Express), database, USB,
>   USB2, 1394/Firewire, etc.

Since a download link for it is somewhat hard to find on sisoftware.net, here it is on [filehippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_sandra_lite/).

[image: image1]

[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) - System Information for Windows

> SIW is an advanced System Information
>   for Windows tool that gathers detailed
>   information about your system
>   properties and settings and displays
>   it in an extremely comprehensible
>   manner.   SIW is a standalone utility
>   that does not require installation
>   (Portable Freeware)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much detail you need, you can try `dxdiag`. Type `dxdiag` into the Run box and hit enter.

For detailed information, the previously mentioned CPU-Z and [**BlackBox**](http://blackbox.hardwaremania.com/en/features) are great. Here's some shots of BlackBox:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's one built in tool you can run from CMD,
try:

```
wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
```