# How do I view the amount of L2 cache in windows?

Tags: windows, cpu-cache

I know where to find CPU class and speed, and amount of RAM.  But I don't see the amount of CPU cache in computer properties or device manager.  Does windows (XP currently) provide this information, or is there a good program to retrieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) from CPUID is a great little tool for finding out information about your processor.

[image]

More detail on the caches:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[BlackBox](http://blackbox.hardwaremania.com/en/features) and [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) were both mentioned in answers to [a related question](https://superuser.com/questions/50662/displaying-motherboard-memory-cpu-info).

[image: BlackBox]

Answer (score 0):

CPU-Z is a good free software where you can find the amount of cache memory and other important stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) is probably your best bet, it reveals all CPU information.

[image]